# Error, 'invalid operands to binary * (have 'long unsigned int' and 'int *')'

Tags: c

Im running into an issue when Im trying to compile my program.

Errors:

```
main.c:26:42: error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'long unsigned int' and 'int *')
         array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)* size);
                                          ^
main.c:30:50: error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'long unsigned int' and 'int *')
         array = (int*) realloc(array, sizeof(int)* size) ;
```

Below is the relevant code:

```
int* arraySize(int* array, int* size)
{
    size = 0;
    while ((size > 20) || (size < 1))
    {
        printf("What is the size of your array? (1 - 20)\n");
        scanf("%d", &size);
        if ((size > 20) || (size < 1))
        {
            printf("Invalid selection.\n");
        }
    }
    //checking if array has been allocated before
    if(array = NULL) 
    {
        array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)* size);
    }
    else
    {
        array = (int*) realloc(array, sizeof(int)* size) ;
    }
    printf("\nSize of array: array[%d]\nReturning...", size);
    return array;
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what’s going on?

TIA

Comment: The error messages should be very clear: The variable `size` is a *pointer* to `int`, and you can't use a pointer in multiplication.

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear? You're aware that `int *` is a pointer and not a number?

Comment: of course with `int *size` lines like `while ((size > 20) || (size < 1))` are wrong too

Comment: You should be using `sizeof(int) * *size` there - notice 2 asterisks. However, your usage of doesn't take into account the fact that realloc can fail too.

Answer (score 2):

You've one * too much in argument size. This makes size a poitner to int. Which in turn needs to be dereferenced (*size rather than simply size) to use the value pointer points to. But i assume its a mistake and u didnt want to make size a pointer.

Change to:

```
int* arraySize(int* array, int size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another unrelated issue you have: your `if` statement is assigning the value `NULL` to `array`. You should be using a double equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this line:

```
array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)* size);
```

and your method signature:

```
int* arraySize(int* array, int* size)
```

its clear that your size is a pointer, and you want to allocate some memory as per the size value; but what you have tried here addressing size address. So, it should be as following:

```
array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * *size);
```

Always remember, for

```
int *size;
size means address of size and *size means values in that address.
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the point of making a dynamic array? can't you declare the array as bellow or something like this?

```
int array[size];
```